# Share inserts done via preparedStatement with JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, prepared-statement, hikaricp

I am doing bulk inserts in Java using HikariCP with PreparedStatments. JPA is used as persistence provider.

Requirement:-

100K inserts in a table via HikariCP(preparedStatement)

Executing native query(or it can be JPQL) to fetch inserted result along with some joins

This all should happen is single transaction.

I was unable to fetch the results from query as preparedstatement is not yet committed.
Is there a better way to do this? I do not want to compromise performance as well!

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't be able to fetch results immediately - this sounds like a setup issue. Inserts should be visible to the same connection in the same transaction. Maybe show your code executing the insert and the read - and try letting JPA control the inserts and the reads if you aren't already.